# Form doing multiple GET methods

Tags: php

**Problem**

I have a select box that will do some action, but I need that specify action to lead to something like this:

```
recover=1&action=accept
```

I am not handling recover=1 GET in that form, so I am really confused on how would I do this?
With links is easy, I just put the `recover=".$row['recover_id']."&action=accept`

What I have tried & didn't work:

```
                <form action='' method='GET'>                   
                <select name='recover=".$row['recover_id']."&action' class='select'>
                    <option value='accept'>Accept</option>
                    <option value='deny'>Deny</option>
                    <option value='delete'>Delete Recovery</option>
                </select>
                <input type='submit' value='GO' class='go'>
```

But then then the link goes like this:

```
?recover%3D59%26action=accept
```

If I manually enter the link like:

recover=59&action=accept

it works.

**Question**

How do I make it work like I want? is there any other method for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="recover" value="<?php echo $row['recover_id']; ?>">
```

It looks like you're outputting HTML as a PHP string (which you shouldn't do), but if that's the case, the syntax would look like:

```
<input type='hidden' name='recover' value='" . $row['recover_id'] . "'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to put the other variable in a hidden field.  It won't show up to the user, but it will get sent when the user submits the form.

```
<form action='' method='GET'>                   
    <select name='action' class='select'>
        <option value='accept'>Accept</option>
        <option value='deny'>Deny</option>
        <option value='delete'>Delete Recovery</option>
    </select>
    <input type='hidden' name='recover' value='<?php echo $row['recover_id']; ?>'>
    <input type='submit' value='GO' class='go'>
</form>
```

Make sure you are checking that the `recover_id` value does not return anything that might throw off the HTML! Always make sure to check inputs and outputs whenever data is involved to avoid broken web pages (or other bad stuff).